# ruby middleware add stack adding middlware

Tags: ruby, stack, addition, middleware

I am trying to add/append middleware to the stack (in config.ru) on certain requests (where request.path == "/hi")

I was trying to do that with Rack::Builder

But i seem to fail at it.

```
Rack::Builder.new do
  use added_middleware1
  use added_middleware2
end.call(@env) if @request.path == "/something"
```

I am not sure if that makes my problem clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@request` variable should only be available when an actual request is happening, but the code you posted is probably getting run at configuration time when the server starts up.  There is example code on the front page of the [Rack::Builder documentation](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Builder.html) showing how to do something like you would want:

```
app = Rack::Builder.new {
   use Rack::CommonLogger
   use Rack::ShowExceptions
   map "/lobster" do
     use Rack::Lint
     run Rack::Lobster.new
   end
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, i have seen that example, but i am trying to add custom middleware containing sinatra child classes to route certain requests arround. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The stack should look more like this:

```
use CommonMiddleware
map '/something' do
  use SpecialMiddleware
  run TheApp.new
end
map '/' do
  run TheApp.new
end
```

Alternatively, you could write a middleware that looks at the request path and runs the other special middleware as needed - sort of like a wrapper for it.  The machinery would look something like this:

```
def initialize app, special_middleware
  @app, @special_middleware = app, special_middleware
end

def call env
  if route_matches?(env)
    @special_middleware.new(@app).call(env) # assumes special_middleware initializer takes no extra parameters
  else
    @app.call(env)
  end
end

def route_matches? env
  # examine the rack environment hash, return true or false
end
```

And the config for using it would look like this:

```
use RouteMatchingMiddleware, SpecialMiddleware
run TheApp.new
```

Comment: Yeah , i figured it out before i saw your post! Thanks, thats how its done, except for **run TheApp.new(application)** the application has to be used as a parameter